# Elegant, concise way to reformat JSON data in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects, reformatting

I receive a JSON result message in the following format from an old database query that I do not have the ability to change at this time:

```
{
  "vsm1": "2429",
  "vsm2": "2488",
  "vsm3": "1968",
  "vsm4": "",
  "vsm5": "",
  "vsm6": "",
  "vsm7": "",
  "vsm8": "",
  "vsm9": "",
  "vsm10": "",
  "color1": "5",
  "color2": "4",
  "color3": "4",
  "color4": "0",
  "color5": "0",
  "color6": "0",
  "color7": "0",
  "color8": "0",
  "color9": "0", 
  "color10": "0",
  "p1mtime": "1549296004",
  "p2mtime": "1549296009",
  "p3mtime": "1549296014",
  "p4mtime": "",
  "p5mtime": "",
  "p6mtime": "",
  "p7mtime": "",
  "p8mtime": "",
  "p9mtime": "",
  "p10mtime": "",
  "inch1": "",
  "inch2": "",
  "inch3": "",
  "inch4": "",
  "inch5": "",
  "inch6": "",
  "inch7": "",
  "inch8": "",
  "inch9": "",
  "inch10": ""
```

}

I would like to re-format it to a more useable object, like so:

```
{ id: 1, vsm: 2429, color: 5, pmtime: 1549296004, inch: 0  }
{ id: 2, vsm: 2488, color: 4, pmtime: 1549296009, inch: 0  }
{ id: 3, vsm: 1968, color: 4, pmtime: 1549296014, inch: 0  }
```

...and so on.

The incoming data is currently limited to ten of each 'section' (vsm1, vsm2, ...vsm10, color1, color2, ...color10, etc.), so a static loop of some sort over the ten elements in each section is how i started, but seemed rather ugly and certainly not flexible.

A smart snippet that would handle n-number of elements in each section would be even better just in case the data goes beyond ten elements, or drops to just three (due to absence of data or pruned data).

I'm thinking of something along the lines of using .forEach(), but admittedly my JSON / Object manipulation skills are rather poor, so I turn to the community in the hope that someone can point me in the right direction or knows of a cool, tight routine/function that achieves what I'm looking for.  Thanks in advance for any insights.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could take an array of the wanted keys with a placeholder for the running number and build new object and push them to the result set.

```js
var data = { vsm1: "2429", vsm2: "2488", vsm3: "1968", vsm4: "", vsm5: "", vsm6: "", vsm7: "", vsm8: "", vsm9: "", vsm10: "", color1: "5", color2: "4", color3: "4", color4: "0", color5: "0", color6: "0", color7: "0", color8: "0", color9: "0", color10: "0", p1mtime: "1549296004", p2mtime: "1549296009", p3mtime: "1549296014", p4mtime: "", p5mtime: "", p6mtime: "", p7mtime: "", p8mtime: "", p9mtime: "", p10mtime: "", inch1: "", inch2: "", inch3: "", inch4: "", inch5: "", inch6: "", inch7: "", inch8: "", inch9: "", inch10: "" },
    keys = ['vsm*', 'color*', 'p*mtime', 'inch*'],
    result = [],
    id = 1;

while (keys[0].replace('*', id) in data) {
    result.push(Object.assign(
        { id },
        ...keys.map(k => ({ [k.replace('*', '')]: +data[k.replace('*', id)]  || 0 }))
    ));
    id++;
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
var data = { vsm1: "2429", vsm2: "2488", vsm3: "1968", vsm4: "", vsm5: "", vsm6: "", vsm7: "", vsm8: "", vsm9: "", vsm10: "", color1: "5", color2: "4", color3: "4", color4: "0", color5: "0", color6: "0", color7: "0", color8: "0", color9: "0", color10: "0", p1mtime: "1549296004", p2mtime: "1549296009", p3mtime: "1549296014", p4mtime: "", p5mtime: "", p6mtime: "", p7mtime: "", p8mtime: "", p9mtime: "", p10mtime: "", inch1: "", inch2: "", inch3: "", inch4: "", inch5: "", inch6: "", inch7: "", inch8: "", inch9: "", inch10: "" },
    templates = [id => `vsm${id}`, id => `color${id}`, id => `p${id}mtime`, id => `inch${id}`],
    result = [],
    id = 1;

while (templates[0](id) in data) {
    result.push(Object.assign(
        { id },
        ...templates.map(t => ({ [t('')]: +data[t(id)]  || 0 }))
    ));
    id++;
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: ooooh!  Never tried templating, and the use of .replace()-ing a placeholder makes perfect sense too (I've even done it in PHP oh-so-many-moons-ago-that-I-forgot).  Both solutions are intriguing!  Thank you for the snippets.   I'll sleep on them and pick a 'winner' in the morning.  :)

Comment: Awesome, I've try to understand your code, it's simple to write but difficult to implement.

Comment: how can i help?

Comment: I chose Nina's answer for the novelty of the solution and that I learned something new.  That is not to say the other answers here provided are any less valid or creative or flexible.  Scott's came a solid second, and I may steal that for another related project.  Thanks to everyone that contributed! :)

Comment: i don't undersand this syntax `while (templates[0](id) in data)` and this `templates.map(t => ({ [t('')]: +data[t(id)]  || 0 }))`. What does the + sign before object value mean?

Comment: @tolotrasmile, it is an [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus), which converts the following to a number, like `Number()` or `parseFloat()`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, with oldObject the object you want to clean:

```
var cleanedObject = {};
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(oldObject)) {
  let index = key.match('[0-9]+');
  cleanedObject[index] = cleanedObject[index] || {};
  cleanedObject[index][key.replace(index, '')] = value;
}
```

The result will be an object where `cleanedObject['1'] = { vsm: 2429, color: 5, pmtime: 1549296004, inch: ''  }`, and so on.

Comment: This is a good start, but it would be nice to fold those ids into the object, and then use `Object.values` to extract what the OP is seeking.  And you might then want to sort the results.

Comment: Correct - I'm looking to extract the number from the keys (which JasonR does), then re-use it as part of the 'record' id.  Sorting is nice but not a requirement as this parsing code is run in node, server-side, and the client can choose whether to sort on id or color (they represent a 'priority' mapped to a color scheme), or even the timestamp.  I still appreciate the input, JasonR!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This solution has a different flexibility than the one from Nina Sholz.  Nina's allows you to match any style of number-containing key.  But it also requires you to add a template in order to do so.  Mine will handle any keys which contain only a single run of digits but nothing more complex.  But it doesn't require you to do anything to handle such templates.

```js
const reformat = data => Object.values(Object.keys(data)
  .reduce(
    (a, k, i, _, d = k.match(/\d+/)[0])  => ({
      ...a, 
      [d]: {...(a[d] || {id: Number(d)}), [k.replace(/\d+/, '')]: data[k]}
    }), {})).sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id)

const data = {"vsm1":"2429","vsm2":"2488","vsm3":"1968","vsm4":"","vsm5":"","vsm6":"","vsm7":"","vsm8":"","vsm9":"","vsm10":"","color1":"5","color2":"4","color3":"4","color4":"0","color5":"0","color6":"0","color7":"0","color8":"0","color9":"0","color10":"0","p1mtime":"1549296004","p2mtime":"1549296009","p3mtime":"1549296014","p4mtime":"","p5mtime":"","p6mtime":"","p7mtime":"","p8mtime":"","p9mtime":"","p10mtime":"","inch1":"","inch2":"","inch3":"","inch4":"","inch5":"","inch6":"","inch7":"","inch8":"","inch9":"","inch10":""}

console.log(reformat(data))
```

I have no idea if you need either sort of flexibility, but these are interesting alternatives to one another.

Comment: This one just edges out over Nina's - never tried templates but looks interesting to me - but not keen on the result set coming out as all-strings.   Just need a simple 'key-name: number' layout so that I can parse and do some math on the values as-is without needing to convert back to numbers.  I guess I could simply strip them out post-processing by converting the whole mess into a string, rip out the "s and then parse it back into JSON.   Thanks to all for the commentary!  Will pick a winner after a good night's sleep.

Comment: The output is strings because the input is strings.  If you don't mind converting the empty strings to zeros, then you could replace `data[K]` with `Number(data[k])`, and get Numbers for everything.  Also, if, as mentioned in a separate comment, you don't care about the sort, it's trivial to remove it here.

Answer (score 1):

I now see that my answer is basically the same as Ninas, haven't seen templating before so that was cool, but seeing as this i the first time i've tried to answer something here I'll just share it anyway.

As Ninas this can handle any length of data.

```js
const data = {"vsm1": "2429",
  "vsm2": "2488",
  "vsm3": "1968",
  "vsm4": "",
  "color1": "5",
  "color2": "4",
  "color3": "4",
  "color4": "0",
  "p1mtime": "1549296004",
  "p2mtime": "1549296009",
  "p3mtime": "1549296014",
  "p4mtime": "",
  "inch1": "",
  "inch2": "",
  "inch3": "",
  "inch4": "",
  };


const vsmRegex = new RegExp("(vsm\\d)");
const keys = Object.keys(data);

const result = [];
let id= 1;

for(let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  if(keys[i].match(vsmRegex)) {
    let object = {
      id: id,
      vsm: Number(data[`vsm${id}`]) || 0,
      color: Number(data[`color${id}`]) || 0,
      pmtime: Number(data[`p${id}mtime`]) || 0,
      inch: Number(data[`inch${id}`]) || 0
    };
    result.push(object);
    id++;
  } else {
    break;
  }
}

console.log(result);
```